# Using XSLT to take data from two XML files and merge into one?

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm trying to merge two tables using XSLT 1.0.

I have a representation of two DB tables in XML. The first table is a set of key-value pairs:

**Table1.xml**

```
<table>
  <row>
    <column name="key">key1</column>
    <column name="value">val1</column>
  </row>
  <row>
    <column name="key">key2</column>
    <column name="value">val2</column>
  </row>
</table>
```

The second table has rows of data:

**Table2.xml**

```
<table>
  <row>
    <column name="A">a1</column>
    <column name="B">b1</column>
    <column name="C">c1</column>
  </row>
  <row>
    <column name="A">a2</column>
    <column name="B">b2</column>
    <column name="C">c2</column>
  </row>
</table>
```

I am trying to take one of the key-value pairs and add insert it as a new column in every row so that it ends up with this:

**Output.xml**

```html
<table>
  <row>
    <column name="A">a1</column>
    <column name="B">b1</column>
    <column name="C">c1</column>
    <column name="key1">val1</column>
  </row>
  <row>
    <column name="A">a2</column>
    <column name="B">b2</column>
    <column name="C">c2</column>
    <column name="key1">val1</column>
  </row>
</table>
```

Comment: "*I am trying to take one of the key-value pairs*" What determines which one?

Comment: The value of the key is what I'm predicating the decision upon. If column = key1 then select val1.

Comment: @LarsH As of now I haven't tried too many solutions. I have spent the better part of the day trying to learn XSLT by going through various tutorials to try and figure this out..

Comment: "*The value of the key is what I'm predicating the decision upon.*" I am afraid that doesn't say much. There are two rows, and each row has a different key/value pair. Why did you pick the first row and ignored the second one?

Comment: "*If column = key1 then select val1.*" If what column = key1?

Comment: @michael.hor257k From table1, I know that I want to select the key-value pair into the new table if, and only if, column[@name=key]="key1". The other values should not be copied over. In effect, I want to select the row where the key is "key1" and create a new column from it in the output table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to select the row where the key is "key1" and create a new
>   column from it in the output table.

Assuming you are processing the `Table2.xml` file, you can do:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:variable name="val" select="document('Table1.xml')/table/row[column[1]='key1']/column[2]" />

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="row">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
        <column name="key1">
            <xsl:value-of select="$val" />
        </column>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are the two main ingredients of the solution:

```
<xsl:variable name="kvp">
  <xsl:variable name="row" select="doc('table1.xml')/table/row[1]"/>
  <column name="{$row/column[1]}">
    <xsl:value-of select="$row/column[2]"/>
  </column>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:template match="row">
  <row>
    <xsl:copy-of select="*"/>
    <xsl:copy-of select="$kvp"/>
  </row>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: This is XSLT 2.0 syntax. OP uses XSLT 1.0.

Comment: Now that XSLT 2.0 is ten years old, I'm having great trouble remembering how to write XSLT 1.0 code, but I've made an attempt.